# How to test method with scanner inside via jUnit?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

Here my test method :

```
 @Test
public void Should_Print_All_Groups_With_Less_Or_Equals_Student_Count() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {

    SchoolDao schoolDao = new SchoolDaoImplementation();
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    assertEquals(schoolDao.findAllGroupsWithLessOrEqualsStudentCount("testDb.properties"), "check");

}
}
```

Here method which I want to test :

```
 @Override
public HashMap<String, Integer> findAllGroupsWithLessOrEqualsStudentCount(String pathToDatabaseProperties) {

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please, enter minimum number of students in groups : ");
    int numberOfStudents = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(main.drawGroupNamesAndNumberOfStudents(main.replaceGroupNumberToGroupName(main.countNumberOfStudentsInGroups(numberOfStudents, pathToDatabaseProperties), connectionFactory.connectToDatabase(pathToDatabaseProperties))));
    return main.replaceGroupNumberToGroupName(main.countNumberOfStudentsInGroups(numberOfStudents, pathToDatabaseProperties), connectionFactory.connectToDatabase(pathToDatabaseProperties));
}
```

But I don't know how can I test method with scanner inside ?

Because now I run the test and program is loading and do nothing.

So maybe smb can help and write properly test. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can mock Scanner.java using Powermockito.
Similar question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805288/powermock-does-not-mock-correctly
Docs :https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should keep user **input as a separate method**. Helps both ways;

It'll reduce redundant code in future and you can **mock that input method**.

Answer (score 0):

With current solution you can't mock Scanner, cause you are creating new Instance while method execution. Here could be two solutions:

1.Make Scanner as class field:

```
public YourClass {
   private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

@Override
public HashMap<String, Integer> findAllGroupsWithLessOrEqualsStudentCount(String pathToDatabaseProperties) {

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();

    System.out.println("Please, enter minimum number of students in groups : ");
    int numberOfStudents = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(main.drawGroupNamesAndNumberOfStudents(main.replaceGroupNumberToGroupName(main.countNumberOfStudentsInGroups(numberOfStudents, pathToDatabaseProperties), connectionFactory.connectToDatabase(pathToDatabaseProperties))));
    return main.replaceGroupNumberToGroupName(main.countNumberOfStudentsInGroups(numberOfStudents, pathToDatabaseProperties), connectionFactory.connectToDatabase(pathToDatabaseProperties));
}

}
```

and then normally mock your Scanner object:

```
@Mock
private Scanner scanner;
...
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
when(scanner.nextInt()).thenReturn(number);
```

2. Make method initialization of Scanner:

public YourClass {

```
@Override
public HashMap<String, Integer> findAllGroupsWithLessOrEqualsStudentCount(String pathToDatabaseProperties) {

ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();

Scanner scanner = getScanner();
System.out.println("Please, enter minimum number of students in groups : ");
int numberOfStudents = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println(main.drawGroupNamesAndNumberOfStudents(main.replaceGroupNumberToGroupName(main.countNumberOfStudentsInGroups(numberOfStudents, pathToDatabaseProperties), connectionFactory.connectToDatabase(pathToDatabaseProperties))));
return main.replaceGroupNumberToGroupName(main.countNumberOfStudentsInGroups(numberOfStudents, pathToDatabaseProperties), connectionFactory.connectToDatabase(pathToDatabaseProperties));
```

}

```
public Scanner getScanner() {
       return new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

and then use @Spy on your class and mock this method:

```
@Spy
private YourClass yourClass;
@Mock
private Scanner scanner;
...
when(yourClass.getScanner()).thenReturn(scanner);
when(scanner.nextInt()).thenReturn(number);
```